# Example of constant r-value

Tags: c++, c++11

Can someone give me an example of a constant r-value?

Cause apparently even literals are r-values and not const r-values.

Comment: rvalues can't be on the left side of assignment so aren't they all constant?

Comment: What do you mean `r-value` but not const `r-value`?

Comment: const rvalue references?

Comment: @Pubby: There are things that require mutable types other than assignment. Consider `const std::string f(); f().append("Hi");` --> fail as the rvalue expression `f()` is `const`.

Comment: @Nick: Strange as it may seem, an *rvalue-reference* is actually an *lvalue*. (Well, the wording before is quite imprecise, the *use* of an *rvalue-reference* is an *lvalue-expression*; r/lvalue applies to expressions)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas,true, I just thought he might be referring to something like this (const T&&)

Comment: @David only when named. The rvalue reference returned from `std::move` is not an lvalue.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: You are right, I still think only on *rvalue* and *lvalue* in the C++03 sense (i.e. *prvalue* vs. everything else). The result of `std::move` is neither, it is an *xvalue*, which is both an *glvalue* and an *rvalue* (just not a *prvalue*) --confusing enough?

Comment: @David it is not as confusing if you think of then as im-values (xvalues), which are both i-values (glvalues) and m-values (rvalues). The others are iM-values (lvalues), which are i-values, but not m-values, and Im-values (prvalues), which are not i-values, but are m-values. (the i means it has an *identity*, i.e., can take address; the m means it can be *moved* from; the uppercase versions are the negation of the lowercase versions; as per http://www.stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Actually I do understand the concepts, but I don't know whether either of the two last comments are clear for the casual reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const T f();
```

With that definition, the expression `f()` is an r-value expression of type `const T`, i.e. a constant r-value.

Comment: LOL, well, that was simple enough :-D Thanks. Btw. any idea why literals are r-values and not const r-values?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: It does not really matter much, does it? (i.e. there are no literals of class type, so literals are not assignable regardless of whether they are `const` or not)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be because "const" means that during the lifetime of something, the value does not change. But a literal is just a mere value itself. It does not refer to an object. What does it mean that "*one* is const"?